# Using Moq to verify a parameter of type List<>?

Tags: c#, moq

Using Moq, I'd like to be able to verify that certain conditions are met on a parameter being passed to a mocked method call.  In this scenario, I'd like to check that the list passed into the mocked method is of a certain size:

```
var mockSomeRepository = new Mock<SomeRepository>();
mockSomeRepository.Setup(m => m.Write(It.IsAny<List<SomeDTO>>())).Verifiable();

var mainClass = new MainClass(mockSomeRepository.Object);
List<SomeDTO> someList = GetListWith25Items();

mainClass.DoRepositoryWrite(someList); // calls SomeRepository.Write(someList);

mockSomeRepository.Verify(m => 
    m.Write(It.Is<List<SomeDTO>>(l => l.Count() == 25)), Times.Once());
```

The verify assert throws an exception that says the method is never called in this fashion.   However, removing the constraint and using `Is.Any<List<SomeDTO>>()` instead leads to a pass. I'm not sure if I'm using It.Is<>() properly here - this is what I intuitively want my test to look like but I'm not sure if I'm using the framework properly.  How should I properly frame this test?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can get rid of the call to *Setup* and *Verifiable* on your mock. Just use *Verify*.

I created a little test-project, and this worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Moq;

namespace csharp
{
    public class SomeDTO { }

    public class SomeRepository { public virtual void Write(List<SomeDTO> list) { } }

    public class MainClass
    {
        private SomeRepository someRepository;

        public MainClass(SomeRepository someRepository) { this.someRepository = someRepository; }

        public void DoRepositoryWrite(List<SomeDTO> list) { this.someRepository.Write(list); }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mockSomeRepository = new Mock<SomeRepository>();
            var someList = Enumerable.Repeat(new SomeDTO(), 25).ToList();

            var mainClass = new MainClass(mockSomeRepository.Object);
            mainClass.DoRepositoryWrite(someList);

            mockSomeRepository.Verify(m => m.Write(It.IsAny<List<SomeDTO>>()), Times.Once(), "Write was not called");
            mockSomeRepository.Verify(m => m.Write(It.Is<List<SomeDTO>>(l => l.Count == 25)), Times.Once(), "Write was not called with a 25-element-list");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing the call to Setup gets me a different error: Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: m => m.Write(It.Is<List`1>(l => l.Count<SomeDTO>() == 25))
No setups configured.

Comment: Maybe your Unit-Test is correct, but your MainClass.DoRepositoryWrite-method is not? Are there any 'Performed invocations' listed in the MockException being thrown? If not, then SomeRepository.Write was never called by mainClass.

Comment: This turned out to be correct, the test was in fact working properly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I had this problem several times. I wrote a test for an existing method, and the test failed over and over again. Looking for the bug in the test, i realised the method was broken, not the test :-)

Comment: And this is why you should use TDD :p

Answer (score 6):

When I posted this question, I was missing a few important details.  I want to elaborate on what was actually happening in case it will help someone in the future.  My method under test was actually clearing the list that was being passed to the mock:

```
public class SomeDTO { }

public class SomeRepository
{
    public virtual void Write(IEnumerable<SomeDTO> list) { }
}

public class MainClass
{
    private readonly SomeRepository _someRepository;
    private readonly List<SomeDTO> _testList = new List<SomeDTO>(); 

    public MainClass(SomeRepository someRepository)
    {
        _someRepository = someRepository;
    }

    public void DoRepositoryWrite()
    {
        _testList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(new SomeDTO(), 25));
        _someRepository.Write(_testList);
        _testList.Clear();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mockSomeRepository = new Mock<SomeRepository>();

        var mainClass = new MainClass(mockSomeRepository.Object);

        mainClass.DoRepositoryWrite();

        mockSomeRepository.Verify(m => m.Write(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<SomeDTO>>()), Times.Once(), "Write was not called");
        mockSomeRepository.Verify(m => m.Write(It.Is<IEnumerable<SomeDTO>>(l => l.Count() == 25)), Times.Once(), "Write was not called with a 25-element-list");
    }
}
```

Looking back it seems a little obvious, but the takeaway here for me is that the mock hangs on to a reference to the list it was passed.  Therefore you need to be careful with any side effects that alter that list.

To write the test properly, I needed to inspect the properties of the passed list immediately when the mocked method was called.  To do this I used a callback:

```
int listCountAtTimeOfCall = 0;
mockSomeRepository.Setup(
    m => m.Write(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<SomeDTO>>())).Callback
        <IEnumerable<SomeDTO>>(list => listCountAtTimeOfCall = list.Count());

... do the work ...

Assert.AreEqual(listCountAtTimeOfCall, 25);
```